# Why can't methyl glycosides mutarotate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I found this link trying to explain it: [Why pyranosides do not mutarotate?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70818/why-pyranosides-do-not-mutarotate) however, I don't understand a step of the reasoning.

*Why* is it that acetalisation needs a stronger acid than for hemi-acetalisation? I was wondering why can't the mechanism be similar to the the one for the mutarotation of glucose as shown below:
[image]

Couldn't the $\ce{O}$ break the bond, and then instead of forming the aldehyde, rotate the $\ce{O-CH3}$ group and then reform the bond?

Comment: the second step, where the proton is removed by a base, woudn't work for a methyl group. [Ether Cleavage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ether_cleavage) needs a strong haloacid such as HI.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb ok, but can't I skip that step and just rotate then whole thing and then reform that bond?

Comment: You can’t skip a step. You either move along the pathway or you hit a dead end/wall.